# How to check a table range and paste selected values to a new worksheet in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I’m trying to check all the rows from 63 to 69 in table 1, if column D value is “ATTIVO” AND column “F” value  >= 130,
i'd like to paste the G column value into another WorkSheet starting from A3 cell.
If the condition is False I’d like to to pass to next row and do the same check for all rows, coping and pasting if the condition is True.

n = 63; LastRow3 = 69.

Table 1:

[image]

Table 2:

[image]

```
Sub Macroarea1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastRow1 As Long, LastRow3 As Long
    Dim i, n, x As Integer
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Report KIT")

    n = Sheets("Migrazioni").Range("N" & 7).Value
    LastRow3 = Sheets("Report KIT").Range("G" & Sheets("Report KIT").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = n To LastRow3
        On Error Resume Next
        If Sheets("Report KIT").Range("D" & x) = "ATTIVO" And Cells(x, 6) >= 130 Then _
        Sheets("Report KIT").Range("G" & x).Copy
        Sheets("KIT").Range("A3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        'Else
        x = x + 1
        'End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

For example for 1st table input I’d like to have a second table as an output.

Unfortunately a VBA gives me an error (that Else condition is not ok). 
I guess I’ve built all the For cycle in a wrong way.
Can anyone help with it, please?

Comment: I would advise not using "On Error Resume Next" unless you know EXACTLY what is happening with you code!!

Comment: What error is the code giving you?

Comment: remove the continuation character '_' at the end of the If... Then line and uncomment the Else and end if lines

Comment: @Vincent G in this case (if i remove _ and uncoment Else and End If) i get a compile error: Else without if

Comment: Shouldn't happen. Did you remove the _ before  or after the comments? You have only one If.. Then and one Else with no End if between.

Comment: By the way you didn't need the Else in any case, see my answer bellow. The x need to be incremented every time, and you will need a variable for the destination row.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Macroarea1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastRow1 As Long, LastRow3 As Long
    Dim i, n, x As Integer, y As Integer
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Report KIT")

    n = Sheets("Migrazioni").Range("N" & 7).Value
    LastRow3 = Sheets("Report KIT").Range("G" & Sheets("Report KIT").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    y = 3
    For x = n To LastRow3
        With Sheets("Report KIT")
        If (.Cells(x, 4).Value2 = "ATTIVO") And (.Cells(x, 6).Value2 >= 130) Then
            .Cells(x, 7).Copy
            Sheets("KIT").Cells(y, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            y = y + 1
        End if
        x = x + 1
        End With
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks it almost does what i need. The only problem, for the string: If .Cells(x, 4) = "ATTIVO" And .Cells(x, 6) >= 130 Then it gives an error: Run- Time error '13': Type mismatch, what could it be?

Comment: you might need to access the data through the Value Property? try `If .Cells(x, 4).Value2 = "ATTIVO" And .Cells(x, 6).Value2 >= 130 Then`

Comment: unfortunately it gives the same error also with the modification specified above

Comment: When it copies 960680/90 value, and passes to the string If (.Cells(x, 4).Value2 = "ATTIVO") And (.Cells(x, 6).Value2 >= 130) Then, the macro stops giving an error